# Using H2 Debug Console occurred exception

Tags: h2, ignite

I have seted `-DIGNITE_H2_DEBUG_CONSOLE` in JVM parameters.
Then local H2 console started.
but exception occurred：

> General error: "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException"; SQL statement:
>       SELECT UPPER(VALUE) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME=? [50000-191] HY000/50000
>       org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException"; SQL statement:
>       SELECT UPPER(VALUE) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SETTINGS WHERE NAME=? [50000-191] 
>           at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) 
>           at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168) 
>           at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:295) 
>           at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:213) 
>           at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:110) 
>           at org.h2.bnf.context.DbContents.readContents(DbContents.java:136) 
>           ...
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
>       Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException 
>           at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2Row.setKey(GridH2Row.java:101) 
>           at org.h2.table.MetaTable.add(MetaTable.java:1982) 
>           at org.h2.table.MetaTable.generateRows(MetaTable.java:940) 
>           at org.h2.index.MetaIndex.find(MetaIndex.java:50) 
>           at org.h2.index.BaseIndex.find(BaseIndex.java:132) 
>           at org.h2.index.IndexCursor.find(IndexCursor.java:169) 
>           at org.h2.table.TableFilter.next(TableFilter.java:460) 
>           at org.h2.command.dml.Select.queryFlat(Select.java:541) 
>           ...
>           at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:110) 
>           at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:201) 
>           ... 8 more

Comment: Does this happen on startup or after you do something on the console?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-3685

It is fixed in upcoming Apache Ignite 1.8.